# Clone SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two computers, one is the main used by people and the other is the backup in case the main stops working. They are both running SQL Server and at the moment whenever I want to sync their data I backup the main computer and restore the backup computer.

Is there an option to clone and on realtime if it's possible an sql server database on another computer running also SQL Server?

After a search I found about `Transactional Replication` is it what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you have 3 options:

- AlwaysOn
- Database mirroring
- Log shipping

`Database mirroing` is going to be deprecated in the future versions of SQL Server so perhaps you should choose between `AlwaysOn` and `Log Shipping`. Depends on what are your actual needs, you can read about differences and options here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190202.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer i will!